# Change the URL of an image from wp_get_attachment_image_src

Tags: images, cdn

I call a lot of images with `wp_get_attachment_image_src()` and would like to off load those images to a CDN.

Is there a filter to grab the URL and change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not strictly. You can [check the source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/media.php#L0) and see that there is no hook that would let you alter the URL.

You should also notice this interesting bit of code:

```
512         if ( $image = image_downsize($attachment_id, $size) )
513                 return $image;
```

Follow the trail to [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/media.php#L136) and you get this:

```
141         // plugins can use this to provide resize services
142         if ( $out = apply_filters( 'image_downsize', false, $id, $size ) )
143                 return $out;
```

If you hook into `image_downsize`...

```
add_filter(
  'image_downsize',
  function ($f,$id,$size) {
    // your own downsize function

  },
  10,3
);
wp_get_attachment_image_src(4);
```

... you should be able to return any URL you want, but it means you will need to duplicate more or less the whole of `image_downsize()` with changes of course.

Comment: The `wp_get_attachment_url` filter might also work.  This applies to the all uploads and not just images.

Answer (score 4):

Just to clarify for anyone might stumble upon this in the future, as of 4.3.0 [a filter to alter the image src](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9/src/wp-includes/media.php#L851) does exist: [wp_get_attachment_image_src](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_get_attachment_image_src/)

```
function alterImageSRC($image, $attachment_id, $size, $icon)
{        
    $image[0] = 'http://newimagesrc.com/myimage.jpg';

    return $image;
}
add_filter('wp_get_attachment_image_src', 'alterImageSRC', 10, 4);
```

**Note:** To filter the srcset of an image use: [wp_calculate_image_srcset](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_calculate_image_srcset/)